# Forensic investigation of Mainframe potential malicious file

Tags: mainframe

I was provided a file that was downloaded from a mainframe that the user thought it was malicious. We have a separate windows 10 environment designed for forensic. Using filezilla the admin connected to the mainframe and downloaded the file into the forensic windows environment.

Upon reviewing the file without internet (offline) I found the file and went to properties. The file shows as a "REPORT FILE." I attempted to open the file with Notepad and Wordpad, both attempts merely showed a collection of un-formated symbols. If my understanding of mainframes is correct data is stored using EBDCIC (extended binary coded decimal interchange code)

I would like to scan the document to find out if there is any hidden scripts or macros and then would like to open the document and find out what is written.

Thank-you for the assistance.

Comment: Google for "ebcdic viewer"

Comment: Thank-you. I found a couple suggestions from the https://groups.google.com/g/bit.listserv.ibm-main/c/hoXLh_wIa1w?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

You need more information about the original mainframe file - is it supposed to be a text file or a data/program file? If text, then just FTP it from the mainframe to the PC as text - the FTP program should do the necessary conversions.

Mainframe files cannot have hidden scripts or macros.

What makes you think it's malicious and why has someone put a malicious Windows program onto the mainframe? Jus in the hope that it gets downloaded to a Windows machine and run?

I suspect someone has downloaded either the wrong file by mistake or the right file but the wrong way (as a binary file not text and so not done the text conversion) and thinks it's malicious because of what appears to be all the strange symbols.

Comment: Thank-you for the response. I am gathering more information and will add a further note afterwards when I receive more information.

Comment: It is believed to be a data/program file.                                                                                  It was believed to be a malicious file as the user did not recognize the file, nor remembers every using that file.                                                                                                                Currently we have attempted to open/inspect the document with notepad, notepad ++, hexEdit(binary), Microsoft word, excel, powerpoint and access.

Comment: @Rbuckle  Why don’t you just examine the file on the mainframe?

Comment: Great question: I am not a mainframe admin. If I was provided access to the mainframe what least permissions would I need for examining.

Comment: You need to get the original mainframe file name and then speak to the mainframe systems programmers (the equivalent to systems admin on linux/Windows). They will be able to look st the file and tell you what it is. If you don't know the mainframe file name, they will be able to upload the file onto the mainframe and examine it's contents. It's extremely unlikely to be malicious as that would mean that someone has somehow manged to upload a malicious Windows program to the mainframe in the hope that someone might download and execute it - not very likely.

Comment: Thank-you for the assistance. I used the program UltraEdit to decipher what the document read and then computed the hash using UltraEdit and PowerShell. Afterwards I ran it against Virus total.